# Block css on a menu generated from XML

Tags: 2013, css, xml

I have this XML statement for a menu

```
 <MenuItem>
<Title>Group</Title>
<Url>#</Url>
<Items>
      <MenuItem>
        <Title>HR</Title>
        <Url>/team/HR/</Url>
      </MenuItem>
  </Items>
```

The default css will change the colour of the title when you hover over it.  I want to stop one line from having the CSS applied, more specifically the change on hover.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use jQuery on page load

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#menuitemid").removeclass("someClass");

});
</script>
```

Comment: Sorry for a amateur question but where does this go? In the XML or masterpage?

Comment: This can go in the masterpage.